# Grails - using subdomain of localhost on run-app

Tags: tomcat, grails, run-app

Is there any way of configuring the embedded tomcat (from run-app) to respond to myapp.localhost:8080  instead of localhost:8080/myapp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your local hosts file so myapp.localhost points to localhost

```
127.0.0.1         myapp.localhost
```

modify the `conf/Config.groovy` and add `grails.app.context = “/”`

Comment: But I will still have to put the URL: http://myapp.localhost:8080/myapp   - I want to configure the server to use the root. It also doesn't matter that the domain is myapp.localhost or just localhost.